# insert a node through webservice in drupal 7

Tags: web-services, drupal, service, drupal-7

i want to insert a node through webservice in drupal 7 and how the service url for insert node looks in drupal 7.
Please help me.

Comment: If you want a better answer than the one bellow you need to give us some more information. Unless your permissions for the node you are trying to create are set to anonymous then you will have to enable authentication your choices are drupals built in session authentication or OAuth?. What format are you intending to send the data in?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Services module](https://drupal.org/project/services). It will allow you to enable REST/SOAP server within Drupal. Within the configuration, you can select the node content type and allow CRUD operations as you wish allowing nodes to be created via the exposed APIs.